# reading 2D array text file java

Tags: java, arrays, file, text, readfile

I am trying to develop a GUI-based program to read the entries of a matrix from a text file. The first number is the number of rows; the second number is the number of columns. The remaining numbers are integers between 1 and 9 in row by row order. Scan the matrix, highlight (display the entries in different color) all cells that form a group of five cells with the same value horizontally, vertically or diagonally.

My program below is NOT reading the file correctly I don't think because every time I click Process in my menu I get in return a matrix of 0's. PLEASE HELP.

**CLASS:**

```
 // GUI-related imports

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

// File-related imports

import java.io.FileReader;   // both needed
import java.io.BufferedReader;  // for line input

import java.io.IOException;


public class FiveInARow
{

 byte[][] tag = new byte[100][100];
 int[][] matrix = new int[100][100];
 int row;
 int col;
 String filePath, fileName;

 // Constructor
 public FiveInARow()
 {
  row = 0;
  col = 0;
 }

 public void ReadFile()
 {
  // Initialize TAG(s) to 0
  for(int i =0; i< tag.length; i++)
    for(int j =0; i< tag.length; j++)
       tag[i][j] = 0;

  //Place open dialogue here
  String filePath = null;
  String fileName = null;

      JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
      chooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG );
      chooser.setDialogTitle("Open Data File");

         int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
         if( returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
          {
             filePath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
             fileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
           }


  // Define & Instantiate File
  Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(filePath);
  row  = inputStream.nextInt();
  col  = inputStream.nextInt();

  for(int i =0; i< row; i++)    // rows
  {
   for(int j = 0; j < col; j++)   //columns
   {
     matrix[i][j] = inputStream.nextInt();
   }

  }

 } // End of ReadFile method



 public void Process()
 {

  // Go through the matrix
  for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < col; j++)
    {
      // Checking the matrix horizantally
      if(j <= col-5)  // Checks the boundaries of horizantal elements

        if (matrix[i][j] == matrix[i][j+1]
            &&(matrix[i][j+1] == matrix[i][j+2])
            &&(matrix[i][j+2] == matrix[i][j+3])
            &&(matrix[i][j+3] == matrix[i][j+4]))

        tag[i][j] = 1;

        // Checking the matrix vertically
       if(i <= row-5)  // Checks the boundaries of vertical elements

        if (matrix[i][j] == matrix[i+1][j]
            &&(matrix[i+1][j] == matrix[i+2][j])
            &&(matrix[i+2][j] == matrix[i+3][j])
            &&(matrix[i+3][j] == matrix[i+4][j]))

        tag[i][j] = 2;

       // Checking the matrix's right diagnol CHANGEEEEE
       if (matrix[i][j] == matrix[i+1][j]
            &&(matrix[i+1][j] == matrix[i+2][j])
            &&(matrix[i+2][j] == matrix[i+3][j])
            &&(matrix[i+3][j] == matrix[i+4][j]))

        tag[i][j] = 3;

       // Checking the matrix's left diagnol   CHANGEEE
       if (matrix[i][j] == matrix[i+1][j]
            &&(matrix[i+1][j] == matrix[i+2][j])
            &&(matrix[i+2][j] == matrix[i+3][j])
            &&(matrix[i+3][j] == matrix[i+4][j]))

        tag[i][j] = 4;
    }
  }


 } // End of Process method





}
```

**DRIVER:**

```
    // GUI-related imports

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

// File-related imports
import java.io.FileReader;   // both needed
import java.io.IOException;

public class  Project3Main extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
 // File Parameters
 FiveInARow f = new FiveInARow();
 String dataFilePath = null;
 String dataFileName = null;
 int[][] Data = new int[100][100];
 int[][] Tag = new int [100][100];
 int row = 0;
 int column = 0;

 // Retrieved command code
 String command = "";

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  Frame frame = new  Project3Main();

  frame.setResizable(true);
  frame.setSize(1000,700);
  frame.setVisible(true);

 }

 public  Project3Main()
 {
  setTitle("2D Arrays");

  // Create Menu Bar
  MenuBar mb = new MenuBar();
  setMenuBar(mb);

  // Create Menu Group Labeled "File"
  Menu fileMenu = new Menu("File");

  // Add it to Menu Bar
  mb.add(fileMenu);

  // Create Menu Items
  // Add action Listener 
  // Add to "File" Menu Group
   MenuItem miReadData = new MenuItem("Read Data");
   miReadData.addActionListener(this);
   fileMenu.add(miReadData);

   MenuItem miProcess = new MenuItem("Process");
   miProcess.addActionListener(this);
   fileMenu.add(miProcess);

   MenuItem miExit = new MenuItem("Exit");
   miExit.addActionListener(this);
   fileMenu.add(miExit);

  // End program when window is closed
  WindowListener l = new WindowAdapter()
  {

   public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev)
   {
    System.exit(0);
   }

   public void windowActivated(WindowEvent ev)
   {
    repaint();
   }

   public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent ev)
   {
    repaint();
   }

  };

  ComponentListener k = new ComponentAdapter()
  {
   public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) 
   {
          repaint();           
      }
  };

  // register listeners
  this.addWindowListener(l);
  this.addComponentListener(k);

 }

//******************************************************************************
//  called by windows manager whenever the application window performs an action
//  (select a menu item, close, resize, ....
//******************************************************************************

 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ev)
  {
   // figure out which command was issued  
   command = ev.getActionCommand();

   // take action accordingly 
   if("Read Data".equals(command))
   {

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// call readfile method in your class to do this
f.ReadFile();



                                dataFilePath = null;
    dataFileName = null;

      JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
      chooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG );
      chooser.setDialogTitle("Open Data File");

         int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
         if( returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
          {
             dataFilePath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
             dataFileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
           }
         try 
     {   


           /*
       * Scan the file and place it's contents into an array of Integers.
       */
       Scanner inputStream  = new Scanner(new FileReader(dataFilePath));
       int intLine;
       row = inputStream.nextInt();
       column = inputStream.nextInt();
        for (int i=0; i < row; i++)
        {
          for (int j = 0 ; j < column; j++)
          {

            intLine = inputStream.nextInt();
          } 
        }
     }

     catch(IOException ioe)
     {
      System.exit(0);
     }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    repaint();
   }
   else
    if("Process".equals(command))
    {
     // call process method in your class 
     f.Process();
     // determine if cells form a 5-cell same-valued block, mark them true in Tags array



     repaint();
    }
   else
    if("Exit".equals(command))
    {
     System.exit(0);
    }

  }
//********************************************************
// called by repaint() to redraw the screen
//********************************************************

  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {

   int ww = (int)this.getWidth();
   int wh = (int)this.getHeight() -40;

   if("Read Data".equals(command))
   {
    // Acknowledge that file was opened
    if (dataFileName != null)
    {
     g.drawString("File --  "+dataFileName+"  -- was successfully opened", ww/2-150, wh/2);
    }
    else
    {
     g.drawString("NO File is Open", 400, 400);
    }

    return; 
   }
   else
   if("Process".equals(command))
   {


    // Display the results
    int x = (ww-column*20)/2;
    int y = (wh-row*20)/2;

    for (int i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
     for (int j=0; j<column; j++)
     {
      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      if (Tag[i][j] == 1)
       g.setColor(Color.RED);
      //******* set color for the other directions

      g.drawString( ((Integer)Data[i][j]).toString(), x, y);
      x=x+20;
     }
    x = (ww-column*20)/2;
    y=y+20;
    }
    return; 
   }

  }

}
```

Comment: First I open the file by clicking Read Data option in the menu, then I cluck Process to actually show my array in the GUI. However I only get 0's I am stuck & don't know what to do.

Comment: If you do a Google search, this will be the most asked question here.

Comment: Can you provide an example of file format

Comment: You need to provide more information. What is the format of the file? Can you provide an example of the file format? What isn't it doing? Where is it fail?  Simply stating that the file isn't reading isn't enough. Why isn't it reading the file, does it cause an exception? Does it exhibit some kind of other, unexpected, behaviour?

Comment: Can you please EITHER explain what your file looks like, OR post it here?  Otherwise, nobody can really work out for you why it's not being read.  Also, exactly what do you mean when you say it's "not reading"?  What exactly is going wrong for you?  And did you try the fixes suggested by the people who have already responded?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(filePath);
```

filePath is a String. Scanner accepts a String in its constructor, but then it treats the String as the source. It'll never load the file.

You need to pass it an InputStream or a File or something else as you do in the Driver.

Comment: What would I have to change this part of my code to to make it work correctly and open my file?

Comment: It's correct in the Driver but in your class it's not.

Comment: You have this in Driver. 'Scanner inputStream  = new Scanner(new FileReader(dataFilePath));'

Comment: I am new at this, sorry...I am totally stress right now and not sure exactly how to go about this program w.o messing up my code.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this not and get back to you. Do I have to delete the one inside my driver, or do I leave that one there as well? It it neccesary to have duplicate?

Comment: See @MikeG010590's answer above. He provides the correct code and you should probably accept that answer as the correct one.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and changed:Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(filePath);   to:    Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(new FileReader(dataFilePath)); but recieved an error message:    Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable dataFilePath
  location: class FiveInARow

Comment: Change dataFilePath to filePath.

Comment: mttdbrd I tried this and got the ERROR when compiling(Error: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown).   // Define & Instantiate File
  Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(new FileReader(filePath)); 
  row  = inputStream.nextInt();
  col  = inputStream.nextInt();
  
  for(int i =0; i< row; i++)    // rows
  {
   for(int j = 0; j < col; j++)   //columns
   {
     matrix[i][j] = inputStream.nextInt();
   }

  }

Comment: I put this in my FiveInARow. class in the ReadFile method

Comment: @user3408177, This is expected. You need a try{}catch{} and optionally finally{} block around the file reading method. In the catch clause you'll need to catch an IOException.

Comment: @user3408177 Look at the Driver class. It shows you how to do it. There's a try{} block in there.

Answer (score 1):

Your file chooser will give you a file you can use directly with your scanner:

```
File chosenFile = null;
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
if( returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
{
    chosenFile =  chooser.getSelectedFile();
}

Scanner inputStream;
// Define & Instantiate File
if (chosenFile != null) {
    inputStream = new Scanner(chosenFile);
} 
else {
    // handle appropriately
}
```

Comment: is chosenFile a String datatype?

Comment: Nope, it's a `File`, it's declared on the first line of my code block.

Answer (score 0):

Change your use of the scanner to be like this:

```
Scanner inputStream  = = new Scanner(new File("filename"));;
String line = scanner.nextLine();
String[] numbers = line.split(" "); 
for(String str : numbers){
  int nunber = Interger.parseInt(str);
}
```

This will read one line of the file at a time, split it on spaces (getting the numbers by themselves) then changing them from a string to a int. I think its getting strings and thus nextInt() has no values and picks up the default.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but the answer makes assumptions about the structure of the data, just saying...

Comment: @MadProgrammer OP posted a bit of the text file before, I think it's going off that. Don't know where the comment with the data went though. It's disappeared.

Comment: It looks like you're passing a string to the Scanner constructor. Does that do what you expect it to do? Also, it looks like you're only passing the file path, which doesn't include the actual file name. I'm the downvoter, I think those are legitimate issues and don't feel like I'm an idiot for pointing them out.

Comment: you can easily change what to split on. That is what is wrong with the code. Scanner returns strings from a file. nextInt() is for System.in

Comment: @MikeB sorry that what a typo, I've updated. Should be taking in a file with a string representing its name and/or path

Comment: @Mike, my teacher gave us this code and expects usto just follow it to finish the rest of the program. If I started this program myself it ightve been a lot easier. Can you please show me what my ReadFile() method should look like because I am pretty sure I am screwing up my code right now following both of your advice...you guys are giving me 2 seperate instructions lol...I just want this thing to work...Would you mind putting in CODE tags please

Comment: I really messed up my code trying to go off what you BOTH were telling me. =/ So stressed...you make it see so simple, but I am new at coding and sorry if I seem "dumb"

Comment: @user3408177 give us some sample input and I can update this code

Comment: FiveInARow ReadFile() method:

Comment: I am trying to post the code I have on here but it says it is "too long"

Comment: @MikeG010590 I would have to input an array from a text file. For ex. this is an array saved as File-1.txt:  7 7/
3 6 2 3 1 6 1/
3 6 6 6 6 6 9/
3 9 3 6 2 9 3/
3 5 9 4 9 5 5/
3 2 8 9 8 6 7/
2 4 9 3 9 9 8/
1 3 9 9 9 9 8......each "/" equal a new line in the array. "7 7" on the top means there are 7 rows, and 7 cols.